# Rails 4: check if a local variable exists and is true in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In a partial, I want to add a class only if the `is_embedded` local variable was passed in and is true. How can I check this?

Currently I check if `is_embedded` is true like this:

**_some_partial.html.erb**

```
<section 
  id="view-dashboard" 
  class="<%= "embedded" if is_embedded %>"
>
```

However this gives an error if `is_embedded` is not passed in: `undefined local variable or method 'is_embedded'`.

Do I always need to pass it in? Or is there a way I can check if it both exists and is true without having errors if it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can check the `local_assigns` hash, which includes the passed locals.

```
<section 
  id="view-dashboard" 
  class="<%= 'embedded' if local_assigns[:is_embedded] %>"
>
```

Answer (score 11):

when rending the partial do this
`<%= render partial: "some_partial", locals:  {is_embedded: true} %>`

```
#_some_partial.html.erb
<%
 #locals
 is_embedded ||= false
%>
<section
id="view-dashboard"
class="<%= "embedded" if is_embedded %>">hhd</section>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check this -

```
if defined?(is_embedded) && is_embedded
```

this will check if is_embedded defined and it is true

Comment: @DonnyP This pattern indeed works in many cases. When two conditionals are joined by &&, if the first one fails then the entire clause is 'false' and the remaining conditionals are never examined. So if is_embedded is undefined, the first statement will return false and the second, the test for non nil/false, will never execute so it won't throw an error. However, it requires correct parenthesis so vee's answer is probably easier.

Comment: there is a gotcha with doing similar approach. for example: <% is_embedded = defined?(is_embedded) ? is_embedded : 'default-embedded-value' %> will not work because ruby will consider is_embedded defined once you declare the variable for assignment

Answer (score 0):

If it is an instance variable,

```
class="<%= "embedded" if @is_embedded %>"
```

Comment: It's in a partial, passed in is a local variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: can you show how you are calling the partial, also the code where you assign is_embedded

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default to false inside the partial if it's not defined:

```rb
<% is_embedded ||= false -%>
<section 
  id="view-dashboard" 
  class="<%= "embedded" if is_embedded %>"
>
```

Comment: Using the - sign used to force ERB to avoid additional spaces.  It's useless in Rails 3+, although it doesn't break anything either.  Just force of habit I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using `local_assigns`, you can use `key?` to check var's presence:

```html
<section 
  id="view-dashboard" 
  class="<%= 'embedded' if local_assigns.key?(:is_embedded) %>"
>
```

That would assume you would never write `is_embedded: false`, because the fact of defining the local would mean "it is embedded".

Or you could use `fetch` to define a default value:

```html
<section 
  id="view-dashboard" 
  class="<%= 'embedded' if local_assigns.fetch(:is_embedded, false) %>"
>
```